# Remove space between two continuous figures in IEEE format paper

Tags: graphics

I am writing two column paper (IEEE format). but I have spaces between two continuous figures. How can I remove these spaces ? Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2in]{}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2in]{}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What's the use of empty `\label{}` and `\caption{}` statements, let alone empty `\includegraphics`?

Answer (score 1):

Put them in the same `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-a}
\caption{my figure}
\label{fig:mine}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-b}
\caption{another figure}
\label{fig:another}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]